# How to display display an IMAGE on a CANVAS using PYTHON's "tkinter" module, Specifically for linux?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, canvas

I've used the following code:

```
# A Python program to display images in canvas
from tkinter import *

# create a root window
root = Tk()

# create a canvas as a child to the root window
c = Canvas(root,bg='black',height=700,width=1200)

# copy images into files
file1 = PhotoImage(file='PYTHON/Graphical User Interface[GUI]/Containers/cat.png')
file2 = PhotoImage(file='PYTHON/Graphical User Interface[GUI]/Containers/puppy.png')

# Display the Image in the canvas in NE direction
# when mouse is placed on cat image, we can see puppy image
id = c.create_image(500,200,ANCHOR=NE,image=file1,activeimage=file2)

# display some text below the image
id = c.create_text(500,500, text= "Displaying Image Demo in tkinter",\
    font = ('Helvetica',30,'bold'), fill='blue')

# add canvas to the root
c.pack()

# wait for any events
root.mainloop()
```

When executed, the above code shows the following error in VScode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/DATA/CodeTrainings/PYTHON/Graphical User Interface[GUI]/Containers/canvasImage(linux).py", line 12, in <module>
    file2 = PhotoImage(file='PYTHON/Graphical User Interface[GUI]/Containers/puppy.png')
  File "/home/lancelot/anaconda3/envs/pyTrain/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/home/lancelot/anaconda3/envs/pyTrain/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "PYTHON/Graphical User Interface[GUI]/Containers/puppy.png": no such file or directory
```

It says that any such file isn't present in the directory but it is indeed present:

[image: Image of file structure]

And, everything works fine in windows, but when it comes to image files in LINUX an error always pops up!
Thanks if anyone could answer my question, but a detailed explanation or pointers on how to handle image files and what are the constraints while working with image files on LINUX is well appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: With relative filenames, python will look in the current working directory which may or may not be the same directory as the script. This has nothing to do with the type or contents of the file. You've simply given an invalid filename relative to the current working directory.

Comment: The Python script and the images are in same folder, so only the filenames without path, for example `'cat.png'`, should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Haha!
I have everything rightly setup, but the only thing where I went wrong is that, while downloading the files, I just renamed the file formats without actually converting them to the required image file format.
This was the problem that caused the error.
I used the online converters to convert the image and everything worked as it has to.
I've learned that renaming doesn't change the internal formatting in the files, therefore it is necessary to convert them using a converter into appropriate formats.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank You!

Comment: You can also delete this Q instead

Comment: While what you wrote is correct, having the incorrect format would not give the error you presented in your question. The file not found error is specifically related to the file _name_ not the file _format_.